# My RGB to Hex is giving me "-"

Tags: python, colors, hex, rgb

I am trying to convert my RGB colors to hex, and when I use
 color = "#%02x%02x%02x" %(r,g,b)
it sometimes gives me hex codes with "-" in them.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: what values of r/g/b are causing this?

Comment: More information is needed. _When_ do you get codes with "-" in them? Try adding something like `if "-" in color: print r, g, b; import pdb; pdb.set_trace();` to your code to get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Without seeing a code sample, we can only guess at the cause. That said, the one case I could think of in which that would happen is when one (or more) of `r, g, b` are negative.

Comment: Blacklight i think you're right but I'm not sure how they are coming out negative.  The values throwing it were 0 -287 542
0 -213 468
0 -5 260
0 -197 452
0 -81 336
0 -27 282
0 -145 400
0 -90 345
0 -16 271

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's because one of `r, g, b` is negative: the dashes are, in fact, the unary `-` operator—possibly better known as the negative-number sign. This becomes more clear if you add commas and whitespace to the format string:

```
>>> "#%02x%02x%02x" % (0, -213, 468)
'#00-d51d4'
>>> "%02x, %02x, %02x" % (0, -213, 468)
'00, -d5, 1d4'
```

Aside from negative numbers, you also have numbers greater than 255. Note that those aren't valid RGB values, either.